# Splitting a variable and putting into an array

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

I have a string like this `<name>sekar</name>`. I want to split this string (i am using perl) and take out only `sekar`, and push it into an array while leaving other stuff.

I know how to push into an array, but struck with the splitting part.

Does any one have any idea of doing this?

Comment: @middaparka, your url got truncated, but not linked :)

Comment: To parse XML, use and XML parser. To parse HTML, use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
push @output, $1 if m|<name>(\w*)</name>|;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my($name) = $string =~ m|<name>(.*)</name>|;
```

From perldoc perlop:

> If the "/g" option is not used, "m//" in list context returns a
>                  list consisting of the subexpressions matched by the
>                  parentheses in the pattern, i.e., ($1, $2, $3...).

Answer (score -1):

Try `<(("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*)>(\w+)<\/\1>`. Should work, when I get home I'll test it. The idea is that the first capture group finds the contents within a `<>` and its nested capture group prevents a situation like `<blah=">">` matching as `<blah=">`. The third capture group `(\w+)` matches the inner word. This may have to be changed depending on the format of the possibilities you can have within the `<tag>content</tag>`. Lastly the `\1` looks back at the content of the first capture group so that this way you will find the proper closing tag.

**Edit**: I've tested this with perl and it works.

Comment: Would have been nice to get a justification for a down vote. I still haven't had a chance to check the code yet so if its wrong let me know and I'll make sure to correct it.